# Enumeration of Enumerations and avoiding the use of Any type

Tags: swift, nested, enumeration, class-design

I'm building a model for an app that tracks data related to wedding dress alterations. Our model diagram shows related enumerations, with "Section" being the outermost enumeration, and then each case connects to an additional, more detailed enumeration.

When the Alteration Specialist is doing the fitting, they will be entering which alterations they plan to do. I need an efficient way to track the relationships between these quantities.

[See object model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw4m3.png)

I have implemented a basic example, but I'm having trouble storing an array of these "Alteration" objects and defining the appropriate type.

Here is my Playground code:

```
struct Alteration {

    var detail: Any

    enum section {
        case bodice
        enum Bodice {
            case addBraCups
            case addOrRemoveBoning
        }
        case sides
        enum Sides {
            case bustTakeInOrOut
            case hipOrWaistTakeInOrOut
        }
    }
}

var alterationOne = Alteration(detail: Alteration.section.Bodice.addBraCups)
var alterationTwo = Alteration(detail: Alteration.section.Sides.bustTakeInOrOut)

var alterations = [Any]()
alterations.append(alterationOne)
alterations.append(alterationTwo)
```

This code compiles but I would prefer to not use `Any`. I'm also wondering if it makes sense to nest enumerations in this manner and if these nested enumerations make sense inside of a struct or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with enums is that they are for things that are mutually exclusive. But yours are not.

I think I would use arrays of alteration types and use classes and subclass to specify what each one is. For example:

```
struct Dress {
    var bodiceAlterations = [BodiceAlteration]()
    var sideAlterations = [SideAlteration]()
}

enum InOrOut {
    case `in`
    case out
}
enum AddOrRemove {
    case add
    case remove
}

class BodiceAlteration {}

class BraCupAlteration : BodiceAlteration {
}

class BoningAlteration : BodiceAlteration {
    var addOrRemove = AddOrRemove.add
}

class SideAlteration {}


class BustAlteration : SideAlteration {
    var inOrOut = InOrOut.out
}

class HipAlteration : SideAlteration {
    var inOrOut = InOrOut.out
}
```

An array can list multiple alterations of its type, and an array can happily be empty if there are no alterations of that type. Then the subclass tells you the more specific type. The enums are just for mutually exclusive choice: a hip alteration can be in or out but not both.

The classes give you room to grow, e.g. add measurements and other data as properties, as appropriate. If you have lots of classes that have inch measurements, dates, etc., you could use a protocol to unite them if you needed to (though if they *all* have that you can just inherit from the superclass).

Comment: Thank you Matt. This has made the work far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try using enums with associated values. Your structs could look like this:

```
enum BodiceVariation {
    case addBraCups
    case addOrRemoveBoning
}

enum SidesVariation {
    case bustTakeInOrOut
    case hipOrWaistTakeInOrOut
}

enum Alteration {
    case bodice(BodiceVariation)
    case sides(SidesVariation)
}

let alterationOne = Alteration.bodice(.addBraCups)
let alterationTwo = Alteration.sides(.bustTakeInOrOut)

var alterations = [Alteration]()
alterations.append(alterationOne)
alterations.append(alterationTwo)
```

(assuming that each of the alterations you've listed are mutually exclusive)

Comment: This is lovely, thank you @Gereon. My next step is to now attach three prices to each xVariation enum. I need a way to get/set minPrice, maxPrice and actualPrice values for each Alteration. Do I declare a computed property inside the Alteration enum, or does that live down inside the xVariation enums? Something like the computed property for "values" shown here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/NestedTypes.html

Comment: This very much depends on how you plan to get and/or calculate the price values. Probably best if you put that in a separate question with more sample code of what you want to achieve.